# how to display the sub-menu items in this drop-down menu

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu

```js
function rotateIcon(m) {
  var key = m;
if ( key === 1)
  {
   
   if(document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right")
     {
      
       document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
       
       }
    else
      {
         document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        }
    
   
    }
  else if(key === 2)
    {
      if(document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right")
     {
      
       document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
       }
    else
      {
         document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        }
      }
 else if(key === 3)
    {
      if(document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right")
     {
      
       document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
       }
    else
      {
         document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        }
      }
  else if(key === 4)
    {
      if(document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right")
     {
      
       document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
       }
    else
      {
         document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        }
      }
  else{
        document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
    }
}

//----------------------------display sub menu starts here---------------------------------------------------//

function displaySubMenu(e) {
    var k = e;
    if (k === 1) {
        if(document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right"){
            document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display= "";
            alert("hai i'm in,you don't see me?");
        }
        else{
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = "block";
        alert("bro..this is my problem,the sub menu is not displaying...!");
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "";
        }
    } else if (k === 2) {
         if(document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className == "spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right"){
              document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display= "";
        }
        else{
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = ""; 
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "";}
    } else if (k === 3) {
         if(document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className == "spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right"){
              document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display= "";
         }
        else{
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = ""; 
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "";}
    } else if (k === 4) {
         if(document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className == "spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right"){
              document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display= "";
         }
        else{
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = ""; 
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "";}
    }  else {
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "";
    }
}
```

```css
 .menu-part{
        margin-top: 120px;
    }
    .menu-parent{
        color: #a6afbb;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 600;
        text-transform: uppercase;
        letter-spacing: 0.05rem;
        padding: 12px 15px!important;
        margin: 20px 0 0 -15px;
        font-family: 'Poppins',sans-serif;
    }
    .sub-menu{
        display: none;
    }
    .sub-menu-parent{
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-top: 25px;
        font-weight: 300;
        color: black;
    }
    .sub-menu-header{
       /* float: left;*/
        padding-left:11px; 
        font-weight: 300;
        font
    }
    .fa.spinner-icon{
        float: right;
        padding-right: 0px;
        font-weight: 100;
    }
    .fa-sliders.menu-front-icon{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    .sub-menu-parent:hover{
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    .spinner-icon{
           /* font-size:13px;
            float: right;
            margin-top: 5%;
            margin-right: 7%;*/
            transition: all 0.6s ease-in-out;
            /*opacity:0.75;*/
    }
    /*.fa.spinner-icon{
        font-size: 13px;
    }*/
    .spinner-icon.in{
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    .spinner-icon.out{
        transform:rotate(0deg);
    }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
              
<ul class="menu-part">
                    <li>
                        <ul class="menu-parent">--- MAIN MENU

                      <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-one" onclick="displaySubMenu(1);rotateIcon(1);"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-sun-o"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">Dashboard</span> <i id="first-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>  
                            <ul id="sub-menu-one" class="sub-menu"> 
                                <li>   <a href="#">Minimalistic</a>    </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#">Demographical</a>   </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#">Analetical</a>      </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#"> Simpler </a>       </li>
                            </ul>
                     </li>

                        <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-two" onclick="displaySubMenu(2);rotateIcon(2);"><i class="menu-front-icon fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">Apps</span> <i id="second-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i> </li>
                            <ul id="sub-menu-one" class="sub-menu"> 
                                <li>   <a href="#">Inbox</a>    </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#">Condact</a>  </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#">Calendar</a> </li>
                            </ul>

                        <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-three" onclick="displaySubMenu(3);rotateIcon(3);"><i class="menu-front-icon fa fa-sliders"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">UI Elements</span><i id="third-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>  
                            <ul id="sub-menu-two" class="sub-menu">
                                <li>    <a href="#">Header</a>  </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Aside</a>   </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Footer</a>  </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-four" onclick="displaySubMenu(4);rotateIcon(4);"><i class="menu-front-icon fa fa-file-code-o"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">Forms</span><i id="fourth-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>  
                            <ul id="sub-menu-two" class="sub-menu">
                                <li>    <a href="#">Header</a>  </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Aside</a>   </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Footer</a>  </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

in the above code i'm trying to implement a drop-down menu with two functionalities.when click on a menu item,

1. icon associated with each menu item need to be rotate 90deg(it's working properly).
2. sub menu items associated with corresponding menu item need to be displayed. (not working)

i tried to put an alert message inside the `javascript` code to check is there any problem,but it's working.i want to fix this error ,how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of your problem starts with the id  `sub-menu-one`, `sub-menu-two`, etc... You should only use these id's once. You have the outer list with class `sub-menu-parent` with an id equal to the child ul id. Removing the id from the parent allows the submenu to become visible.

It also appears that some of your id's in HTML may have a copy past error, for example the child ul list of parent 2 has a id of `sub-menu-one`

https://jsfiddle.net/qp4g5wuw/1/

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code and I noticed that you have just create two **id** with the same name. Which cause this problem. 
I have changed your some code and it is working fine. check it out

First of all I changed you id of following code:

```
    <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-one" onclick="displaySubMenu(1);rotateIcon(1);"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-sun-o"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">Dashboard</span> <i id="first-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>  
                                <ul id="menu-one" class="sub-menu"> 
                                    <li>   <a href="#">Minimalistic</a>    </li>
                                    <li>   <a href="#">Demographical</a>   </li>
                                    <li>   <a href="#">Analetical</a>      </li>
                                    <li>   <a href="#"> Simpler </a>       </li>
                                </ul>
                         </li>

                            <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-two" onclick="displaySubMenu(2);rotateIcon(2);"><i class="menu-front-icon fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">Apps</span> <i id="second-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i> </li>
                                <ul id="menu-two" class="sub-menu"> 
                                    <li>   <a href="#">Inbox</a>    </li>
                                    <li>   <a href="#">Condact</a>  </li>
                                    <li>   <a href="#">Calendar</a> </li>
                                </ul>

                            <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-three" onclick="displaySubMenu(3);rotateIcon(3);"><i class="menu-front-icon fa fa-sliders"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">UI Elements</span><i id="third-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>  
                                <ul id="menu-three" class="sub-menu">
                                    <li>    <a href="#">Header</a>  </li>
                                    <li>    <a href="#">Aside</a>   </li>
                                    <li>    <a href="#">Footer</a>  </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-four" onclick="displaySubMenu(4);rotateIcon(4);"><i class="menu-front-icon fa fa-file-code-o"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">Forms</span><i id="fourth-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>  
                                <ul id="menu-four" class="sub-menu">
                                    <li>    <a href="#">Header</a>  </li>
                                    <li>    <a href="#">Aside</a>   </li>
                                    <li>    <a href="#">Footer</a>  </li>


 </ul>
                        </li>
```

Notice I changed your id **sub-menu-one** to **menu-one** and so on...

After that I changed some of your javascript code because of same id :P

so your full code is like this,

**JavaScript**

```
function rotateIcon(m) {
  var key = m;
if ( key === 1)
  {

   if(document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right")
     {

       document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";

       }
    else
      {
         document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        }


    }
  else if(key === 2)
    {
      if(document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right")
     {

       document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
       }
    else
      {
         document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        }
      }
 else if(key === 3)
    {
      if(document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right")
     {

       document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
       }
    else
      {
         document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        }
      }
  else if(key === 4)
    {
      if(document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right")
     {

       document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
       }
    else
      {
         document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right";
         document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
          document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        }
      }
  else{
        document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className="spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
        document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className = "spinner-icon out fa fa-chevron-right";
    }
}

//----------------------------display sub menu starts here---------------------------------------------------//

function displaySubMenu(e) {
    var k = e;
    if (k === 1) {
        if(document.getElementById("first-drop-down-icon").className=="spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right"){
            document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display= "block";
            document.getElementById("menu-one").style.display= "none";

        }
        else{
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("menu-one").style.display= "block";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "";
        }
    } else if (k === 2) {
         if(document.getElementById("second-drop-down-icon").className == "spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right"){
              document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display= "";
              document.getElementById("menu-two").style.display= "none";
        }
        else{
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("menu-two").style.display= "block";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = ""; 
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "";}
    } else if (k === 3) {
         if(document.getElementById("third-drop-down-icon").className == "spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right"){
              document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display= "";
              document.getElementById("menu-three").style.display= "none";
         }
        else{
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("menu-three").style.display= "block";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = ""; 
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "";}
    } else if (k === 4) {
         if(document.getElementById("fourth-drop-down-icon").className == "spinner-icon in fa fa-chevron-right"){
              document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display= "";
              document.getElementById("menu-four").style.display= "none";
         }
        else{
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("menu-four").style.display= "block";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = ""; 
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "";}
    }  else {
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-one").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-two").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-three").style.display = "";
        document.getElementById("sub-menu-four").style.display = "";
    }
}
```

**HTML Form**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<ul class="menu-part">
                    <li>
                        <ul class="menu-parent">--- MAIN MENU

                      <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-one" onclick="displaySubMenu(1);rotateIcon(1);"><i class="flip-menu-main-icon fa fa-sun-o"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">Dashboard</span> <i id="first-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>  
                            <ul id="menu-one" class="sub-menu"> 
                                <li>   <a href="#">Minimalistic</a>    </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#">Demographical</a>   </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#">Analetical</a>      </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#"> Simpler </a>       </li>
                            </ul>
                     </li>

                        <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-two" onclick="displaySubMenu(2);rotateIcon(2);"><i class="menu-front-icon fa fa-envelope-o"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">Apps</span> <i id="second-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i> </li>
                            <ul id="menu-two" class="sub-menu"> 
                                <li>   <a href="#">Inbox</a>    </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#">Condact</a>  </li>
                                <li>   <a href="#">Calendar</a> </li>
                            </ul>

                        <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-three" onclick="displaySubMenu(3);rotateIcon(3);"><i class="menu-front-icon fa fa-sliders"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">UI Elements</span><i id="third-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>  
                            <ul id="menu-three" class="sub-menu">
                                <li>    <a href="#">Header</a>  </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Aside</a>   </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Footer</a>  </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="sub-menu-parent" id="sub-menu-four" onclick="displaySubMenu(4);rotateIcon(4);"><i class="menu-front-icon fa fa-file-code-o"></i><span class="sub-menu-header">Forms</span><i id="fourth-drop-down-icon" class="spinner-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>  
                            <ul id="menu-four" class="sub-menu">
                                <li>    <a href="#">Header</a>  </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Aside</a>   </li>
                                <li>    <a href="#">Footer</a>  </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
```

Hope you understand it. I am in hurry :P